# Both tests are returning false even though in my mind the code executes perfectly

Tags: ruby, methods

```
# Write a method that takes in a string. Your method should return the
# most common letter in the array, and a count of how many times it
# appears.
#
# Difficulty: medium.

def most_common_letter(string)
letter = 0
letter_count = 0
idx1 = 0
mostfreq_letter = 0
largest_letter_count = 0


while idx1 < string.length 
    letter = string[idx1]
    idx2 = 0
    while idx2 < string.length
      if letter == string[idx2]
        letter_count += 1
      end
      idx2 += 1
    end


  if letter_count > largest_letter_count
    largest_letter_count = letter_count
    mostfreq_letter = letter
  end
  idx1 += 1
end

return [mostfreq_letter, largest_letter_count]
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts(
  'most_common_letter("abca") == ["a", 2]: ' +
  (most_common_letter('abca') == ['a', 2]).to_s
)
puts(
  'most_common_letter("abbab") == ["b", 3]: ' +
  (most_common_letter('abbab') == ['b', 3]).to_s
)
```

So in my mind the program should set a letter and then once that is set cycle through the string looking for letters that are the same, and then once there is one it adds to letter count and then it judges if its the largest letter count and if it is those values are stored to the eventual return value that should be correct once the while loop ends. However I keep getting false false. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: hint: make sure you reset variables to zero at the right place

Comment: there's a flaw in your logic. Try debugging with this ```puts "letter: #{letter}, letter_count: #{letter_count}"``` after your second while loop and see if you can figure it out. But like one of the answers says, def better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not return `[false, false]` to me; but it does return incorrect results. The hint by samgak should lead you to the bug.

However, for a bit shorter and more Rubyish alternative:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  Hash.new(0).tap { |h|
    string.each_char { |c| h[c] += 1 }
  }.max_by { |k, v| v }
end
```

Create a new `Hash` that has a default value of `0` for each entry; iterate over characters and count the frequency for each of them in the hash; then find which hash entry is the largest. When a hash is iterated, it produces pairs, just like what you want for your function output, so that's nice, too.